# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yarnlib'

Tags: python, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I am new to working with react js and just picked up a sample code and tried to run it using the "yarn" command but the error is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/bin/yarn", line 32, in 
> import yarnlib
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yarnlib'

soo I tried running

> which yarn

> cat /usr/bin/yarn

```html
#! /usr/bin/python
# Copyright 2013  Lars Wirzenius
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
# =*= License: GPL-3+ =*=


import cliapp
import collections
import locale
import logging
import os
import re
import shutil
import sys
import tempfile
import time
import ttystatus

import yarnlib
```

and there on line 32, it has import yarnlib

I don't know how to install yarnlib

can somebody help me out with it?

Comment: Check [this article](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install).

Comment: any yarn command is not working

Comment: Thanks to all those who tried to help me out..!
The answer here solved my issue 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64043900/17849317

Basically what it did was to remove nodejs and then re-install it and update the npm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all those who tried to help me out..!
The answer here solved my issue

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64043900/17849317)

Basically what it did was to remove nodejs and then reinstall it and update the npm...and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Did you downloaded the module? If no, go to Terminal (macOS) or Command Prompt (Windows) then enter
`pip3 install yarnlib`

Comment: yes then the error is -> 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement yarnlib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for yarnlib

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell Download from here

Comment: no its not working . any yarn command is not working

Comment: Did you follow https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install insturctions to download?

Comment: This solved my issue..thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64043900/17849317

Answer (score 0):

try `yarn --version`，maybe it still no module yarnlib，
then `npm install npm -g` ， `sudo npm install --global yarn`.
I encounter same problem，then I update npm， reinstall yarn，it works.

Comment: Thanks...But this answer here solved my issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64043900/17849317